# Find row based on condition and output new dataframe with this row AND the following row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I have a data frame which I want to extract 2 rows which correspond to the **first occurring** last positive row and the first negative row.

for example if this is my df:

```
  col1  col2
0     1  0.60
1     2  0.42
2     3  0.78
3     4  0.50
4     5 -0.33
5     6 -0.55
6     7 -4.00
7     8  0.6
8     9  0.5
```

my new data frame would be:

```
  col1  col2
3     4  0.50
4     5 -0.33
```

My initial attempt was to find the row corresponding to the last positive number using:

```
last_posnum = None
for num in df['col2']:
    if num <= 0:
        break
    last_posnum = num

df_new = df.loc[df['col2'] == last_posnum]
```

but I am stuck on how to include the next row in the new dataframe. Would love any tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a different approach:

Since the first occurrence of last positive row is the row before the first negative one, then we can do this:

```
# index of the first neg row
first_neg_index = df[df['col2'] < 0].index.min()
new_df = df.loc[first_neg_index-1:first_neg_index]
```

Comment: The first_neg_index worked fine but the last_pos_index throws an index error (Boolean index has wrong length) - I'm not enough of an expert to know why

Comment: @travgeol you are right, in fact, that line was not necessary, I edited the response

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
#select the last positive row
df_pos = df.loc[df['col2'] > 0 ].tail(1)
#select the first negative row
df_neg = df.loc[df['col2'] < 0].head(1)
#join together
df = df_pos.append(df_neg)
```

or one line of code:

```
df = df.loc[df['col2'] > 0 ].tail(1).append(df.loc[df['col2'] < 0].head(1))
```

Comment: I think I needed to clarify some more - the problem I also have is that  here is that there are rows where there are positive values once again so this just extracts the last, last positive row (when I need the first last positive row). I will edit the original question to clarify this.

Comment: However, the df_neg does work as it will always be the first occurring negative number so i guess in combo with my initial attempt I can join together this solution and my 'last pos num' solution. Probably not the most elegant way for me to do it but thanks for introducing me to .tail and .head :)